# Restricted probability

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

I want to simulate a network evolution through a Markov process. The simulation is about disease spread and so each node as (in a first simulation) only two states: infected of not infected. I want to start with a single infected node and once infected it will become in this state forever. The infected node will infect its neighbours with probability p_{ij}, for the infected node i, and non-infected node j.   Now, in each step I want a single infection to occur. So, my problem is how do I simulate this process with the restriction of a single infection per iteration. In this iteration I could calculate the probability of 0, 1, 2,... or n infections and then simulate from it. But I want the restriction of just one infection per iteration. At first I thought: well, I just need to calculate the probability of 0 and 1 infections. But is this correct? Because then, in the simulation, I'm not considering the cases that in the simulation process would result in 2, 3 ... or n infectious. Or, by other words, by considering just 0 or 1 infections probability, I not using a normalized probability to 1.